# How do I print out this multidimensional php array into a json object?

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I  have a multidimensional php array which I am trying to printout in json format

This is the array

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Zeninjor Enwemeka [title] => At Boston Forum, Federal And Local Officials Discuss Region�s Transportation Future [published] => 2015-10-14 12:22:00 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Zeninjor Enwemeka [title] => Boston�s Transportation Future? City Releases Report Detailing Public�s Transit Goals [published] => 2015-10-09 09:17:00 ) [2] => Array ( [name] => Ryan caron King [title] => Sen. Murphy Seeks Feedback From �Fed Up� Car Commuters [published] => 2015-10-15 16:25:00 ) [3] => Array ( [name] => patrick skahill [title] => Solar Installations Skyrocket, But Connecticut Consumers Still Need to Do Their Homework [published] => 2015-10-15 09:12:00 ) )
```

I have tried this but it did not work:

```
print_r($output_result);
$output = array();
foreach($output_result as $v) {
    $output[key($v)] = current($v);
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Just json_encode $output_result!

Comment: The solution is to directly encode `$output_result`. Otherwise, if your goal is different, please add more details and an **example of desired output**

Comment: I tried json_encode on output_result and it's returning nothing.

Comment: never mind, my array was not UTF encoded